# Android, widgets unavailability unknown reason

Tags: android, widget

I have a little problem with widgets availability in menu "desktop->add->widget->".
I can't figure out why my widgets are not accessible on small screen (ldpi) and when it has been moved to sdcard. 
**Manifest**

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:process="@string/app_name"
        android:persistent="true" android:debuggable="false"
        android:description="@string/app_desc"> 
        <receiver android:name="widget.Widget_4_1" android:label="Rozmiar 4x1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_provider_4_1" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

**Widget Provider**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dip"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget41"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="@string/UpdatePeriod"
    android:minHeight="72dip"/>
```

**Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Widget41"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:background="@drawable/frame41"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/widgettextview41"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="@string/widget_loading"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:textSize="5pt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

re: moving to sdcard and losing the widget

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html#ShouldNot
"... you should not allow your application to be installed on the external storage if it uses any of the following features ... App Widgets ..."

ie, it's a known and documented limiation.

re: ldpi,

not sure if it will solve it for you, but if in uses-sdk you set minSdkVersion to whatever is appropriate and set targetSdkVersion to something high (eg 11 stating honeycomb compat), then you don't need supports-screens as targetSdkVersion effectivly implies / sets defaults for all sizes supported by targetSdkVersion.

Comment: problem with widgets on ldpi is still unsolved (this clue doesn't help). Thank you for the reference about "ShouldNot" :)

Comment: is the minWidth in your provider too big for a ldpi device? hack it back to a smaller number to test

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. The problem was the value of `android:updatePeriodMillis` in widget provider. It looks like you cannot reference a value from resources in this place. So replacing the reference with actual number (eg. 1800000) fixes the problem.

That worked on SE Xperia X10 mini pro with Android 2.1. I had no such problems on devices running Android 2.2.